# appendChild + createElement

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

What's the difference between:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');//output -> [object HTMLDivElement]

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);
```

and:

```
var div = '<div></div>';

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);//output -> <div></div>
```

Shouldn't both be the same? And if not, how do I get the second version to work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The latter is simply a string containing HTML while the first is an object. For the first, you need `appendChild` while for the second, you need to append to `innerHTML`.

> shouldn't both be the same? and if
>   not, how do i get the 2nd version to
>   work?

```
var div = '<div></div>';
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += div;
```

Comment: if you're happy with the answer you should tick it as accepted. note that `+=` is the operator that closest approximates the `append` behavior, not `=`.

Comment: "The later is pure html...". It's just a string.

Comment: You can also use `insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', div)`  in second case

Answer (score 10):

With your JS/DOM engine, calling `Element.appendChild` with a `string` as an argument causes a new `Text` node to be created then added.

Your first example creates a `<div>` element.  Your second example creates a text node with `<div></div>` as its contents.

Your second example is equivalent to:

```
var div = '<div></div>';

document.getElementById('container').appendChild(document.createTextNode(div));//output -> <div></div>
```

As [Sarfraz Ahmed mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895318/appendchild-createelement/2895338#2895338), you can make the second example work how you want it to work by writing:

```
var div = '<div></div>';

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = div;
```

Comment: is there really any browser where passing a string argument causes a new text node to be created and added? in firefox and chrome, this just causes an illegal argument exception, and nothing is added: http://jsbin.com/omofo3/edit

Comment: @David Hedlund, I was explaining the behaviour the poster was experiencing.  I didn't test any browsers (I probably should have).  You're right; this seems to be an exceptional case.

Answer (score 4):

`appendChild` really does expect a HTMLDomNode of some kind, such as a `HTMLDivElement`, and not a string. It doesn't know how to deal with a string. You could do

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += div;
```

but I really prefer the first version; and I'd rely more on it to behave the same across browsers.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to this method? It's how I typically achieve this.

Comment: this is not preferred as this removed the event listeners and also the state of previous elements.

Answer (score 2):

appendChild is expecting an element so when you send it text, it doesn't know what to do. You might want to look into using a javascript library to ease some of that work, such as jQuery. Your code would be:

```
$('#container').append('<div></div>');
```

Comment: There _so_ needs to be a 'hold on, 2 other people are typing answers right now' message when typing up the answer, lol

Comment: while i think it would be overhead to include jquery *only* for this, it's can still be argued that *if* OP was already using jQuery, this might very well have been the solution closest to what OP wanted, so i think it's a worthy alternative, that shouldn't be lost just because somebody else has offered a solution already.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution and support all browsers is:

```
var div = '<div></div>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var myDiv = parser.parseFromString( html, "text/xml" );
```

Another solution may be:

```
var div = '<div></div>';
var tmpDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tmpDiv.innerHTML = div;

    elDiv = tmpDiv.childNodes[0]; //Now it can be used as an element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use these to append/prepend an element to the DOM respectively:

```
var elem = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement(element));
var elem = document.documentElement.prepend(document.createElement(element));
```

and use the `elem` variable to target the element (e.g):

```
elem.style.display = "block";
elem.style.remove();
elem.style.id = ...;
```

etc.