# Why i couldn't append a child node to the document object model directly?

Tags: javascript, dom

While studying the Document object model today, I faced a problem of appending a newly created child on the document object directly,
here is my code :

```
var newEl=document.createElement("textarea");
document.appendChild(newEl);
```

the resulted error is :

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.

I know the solution is to either append it to **document.body** or **document.documentElement** , but I didn't find a **reference** pointing that the mentioned way is not correct for a specific reason.

accept my apologies for being a beginner.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895318/appendchild-createelement

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER i don't think so.

Comment: @BASEERHAIDER :  !! duplicate, your mentioned question asking about append child of a div tag, and my question is asking about add a direct child to document object, did you understood both of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for if what you want to do is understand the spec and constraints surrounding the different items in the [Node Tree](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-tree). Basically, the Document can have only 1 type (HTML or XML) and 1 element/child (e.g `<html>`) and the element (`<html>` tag) can have multiple children (`<body>`, `<head>`, etc..), attributes, etc.. So the element (`<html>`) and its children can be appended to, but the document itself cannot.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this error so wanted to clarify the reason ,
What you are doing using this command `document.appendChild(newEl);`, is trying to add an element to the main document, but the main document has only one element allowed which is the main  `<html>` tag.

So what you can do is either pick another element, or if you want to add it to the displayable area you should use `document.body.appendChild(newEl)`