# How to print each element of an array on a separate line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, newline

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to build a client-side reference extractor for scientific PDFs. I want each reference on a separate line. I have tried `'\n'` and `'<br>'`, they do not work.  Here is an example:

```js
references = ["1", "2", "3"];
document.getElementById("output").textContent = references.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <div>Extracting...</div>
</div>
```

My output is

> 1<br>2<br>3

Answer (score 4):

You should use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead of [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) with `<br />`.
With `textContent`, the "value is not parsed as HTML"; see [Differences from innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML).

```js
references = ["1", "2", "3"];
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = references.join('<br>');
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <div>Extracting...</div>
</div>
```

You can also use [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) but then you have to use `\n` line separator instead of `<br />`

```js
references = ["1", "2", "3"];
document.getElementById("output").innerText = references.join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <div>Extracting...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to iterate through each element in the array like this:

```js
references = ["1", "2", "3"];
references.map((reference) => {
  const node = document.createElement('p');
  const textnode = document.createTextNode(reference);
  node.append(textnode);
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(node);
})
```

```html
<div id="output">
  <div>Extracting...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want each item in 'references' to be it's own HTML element, you can try looping over the array, creating a new element, and attaching it to the DOM.

```
for( const ref of references){
        let newEl = document.createElement('div');
        newEl.innerHTML = ref;
        document.body.appendChild(newEl);
  }
```

Comment: Please consider `document.body.appendChild(newEl)`. See: [couldn't append a child node to the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662168/why-i-couldnt-append-a-child-node-to-the-document-object-model-directly).