# Next.js 14 use client component in server component

Tags: next.js

I have been trying next.js and came across a situation where i need my client component i,e a Loader component to be rendered in the server component. But as soon as i am including the Loader component it throw an error which says

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only
> one element on document allowed.

here is my Loader component

```js
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "@/lib/reducers";
    
const Loader = () => {
  const loading = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.loading);
  return <div>{loading ? "Loader" : null}</div>;
};
    
export default Loader;
```

and here is the server component, which is also my root layout which renders Loader

```js
import "./globals.css";

import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Loader from "@/components/Loader";
import { Providers } from "@/lib/providers";
import SessionWrapper from "../components/SessionWrapper";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <Providers>
      <Loader /> //this throws error when used
      <SessionWrapper>
        <html lang="en">
          <body className={`${inter.className} min-h-screen`}>{children}</body>
        </html>
      </SessionWrapper>
    </Providers>
  );
}
```

here is the provider component which is a client component and a wrapper around the entire layout

```js
'use client';

import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

Is there a way we could render client component here cause if I use this Loader component in any other server compoent let's say - pages/dashboard/layout.tsx, it works fine.

Comment: What is the last provider you are using? maybe it expects only 1 element inside of it. try putting `Loader` and `SessionWrapper` in a react fragment: `<>...</>` or a `div`

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan updated the post including the code for provider component as well, it takes children, so the number of elements doesn't matter i guess

Comment: I still don't know where the `Provider` comes from :) what's the library?

Comment: its from react-redux , which is imported as import { Provider } from "react-redux";

Comment: checkout this documentation for using redux with NextJS 14. maybe it solves your problem (https://redux.js.org/usage/nextjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you an example to demonstrate what you are doing exactly, then, I will explain further.

If I asked you: In a regular HTML, does the below code make sense?

```html
<div>I'm living besides html tag!</div>
<html lang="en">
  <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

Exactly! No, it doesn't. You can't have `div` or any element besides `html` element. It's a bad and unconventional way of writing HTML. Though, it's going to work due to the capabilities of modern web browsers which can parse the HTML and display the content even if the HTML is not perfectly structured.

However, In **Next.js** there is a stricter rules that would make your app fail because of such issues. Now, If you are wondering *where did I make such a mistake?* check the below code.

```js
<Providers>
  <Loader />
  <SessionWrapper>
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} min-h-screen`}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  </SessionWrapper>
</Providers>

// The above will be translated to something like:

<div>Loader...</div>
<html lang="en">
  <body class="YOUR_ClASSES">{/* YOUR CONTENT */}</body>
</html>
```

and that's why in other components it's working properly because it resides inside the `body`.

### Solution

One solution could be to provide two loaders, one for the root component and another one for the rest of the components.

The root component loader could look like:

```js
"use client";
import { RootState } from "@/lib/reducers";
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Loader = () => {
  const loading = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.loading);
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div>{loading ? "Loader" : null}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

[Remember that the Document can have only 1 type (HTML or XML) and 1 element/child (e.g html)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47662479/7918037)